# What is the best practice of store datetime in a database?

Tags: database, datetime, database-design, timestamp

I am working on buy order table for store client's record from frontend side and my case:

1. Client would which come from different countries, different timezones
2. My database server timezone is on UTC+1
3. Daylight saving time might apply in some countries
4. Some clients might buy a product from country A, then buy another product from country B the next day but on different timezones
5. Some client (travelers) which come from country A (UTC+2) and bought items in country B (UTC+0) via his phone (UTC+3, I don't know why but they are)

Here are my questions:

1. What is the best practice to store the datetime in the database?
2. Does frontend side need to convert timezones from client to database?
3. Does backend side need to convert timezones from database to client? How do I determine a client's current timezone?
4. What is the best practice to show datetime from server to website for client review?
5. **(New)** How do I handle `available_delivery_date` and `available_delivery_time` which those fields input by client?

==================

**[ Update 1 ]**
An addition description about question point 5, my order table have 2 fields named `available_delivery_date` and `available_delivery_time` which input by client with their timezone, what is the best practice to save the record?

Comment: If client's timezone is set correctly then you may use TIMESTAMP datatype. If you doubt that the client timezone settings are correct then use DATETIME datatype plus additional column which stores the timezone (its mnemonic name or its timeshift) provided by client. In last case do not forget to import timezones info - it is not filled with data during std. installation process.

Comment: Store unixtime for past events, local time for future events

Comment: Related: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/

Comment: @Akina this is a new idea about `additional column which stores the timezone  provided by client` in my mind! It is easy to show the time for client when reviewing, but I think additional column is not easy to manage and show the report?

Comment: @Evert I think it is a good solutions in my problem, but how can which side (frontend/backend) change the date to unixtime?

Comment: @FObersteiner it is a nice thing about “the instant at which something occurred” and remind me that i missing one concept: How do I handle `delivery datetime` which field input by client?

Comment: *but I think additional column is not easy to manage and show the report* What is the problem to execute `SELECT CONVERT_TZ(datetime_column, '+00:00', timezone_column) AS local_datetime, ...`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Everything is depending on future use cases and your requirement. No format is standard whatever works best for you.

*What is the best practice to store the datetime in the database?*
-If you need to perform calculation like days from purchase using date store it in either datetime or timestamp. Storing as varchar and parsing before calculation also can be done.

*Does frontend side need to convert timezones from client to database?*
-Make backend use one standard time format and on response pass date from server date and time so that your time would be standard for all users.

*Does backend side need to convert timezones from database to client? How do I determine a client's current timezone?*
-Use servers date and time to standarize your time formats.

*What is the best practice to show datetime from server to website for client review?*
-Best practice is to use backend to insert server time on insert query so that server time would be standard for all users. You can fetch the row and pass it to frontend which is based on server time

Comment: Thanks! That thing might help me to log the buy date and buy time. But how do I handle delivery datetime which field input by client?